# Javascript recursion doesn't know when to quit

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, lodash

I have this json object https://gist.github.com/motleydev/f49c779b3ed8c6522df9 that I am transforming with lodash. I am trying to build a lineage of an individual item by using some recursion to loop through the mother/father entries until there are no more valid entries.

Here's the function I'm using:

```
function getLineage(id) {
        var data = horses[id];

        if (!data){
            return; 
        } 
        else
        {
            return {
                name: data.name,
                father: getLineage(data.father),
                mother: getLineage(data.mother)
            };

        }
    };
```

It worked with one or two generations but now with this larger dataset I either A: get a callstack exceeded warning if I don't put a kill switch in after x number of loops, or B: with the limit in place it doesn't loop over all the data, even ones with confirmed mother, father entries. I'm only using 15 of those entries as starting points for the recursion, too. Let me know if there's something that would help make this question clearer.

Thanks.

Comment: What "id" value is the starting point?

Comment: Is it possible you have a loop in your data, where one horse points to a father/mother, etc. etc. which ends up back at the original horse?

Comment: `if(data.father==id || data.mother==id) return;`  fixes it for every single horse

Comment: For example: record 331314307773 has as its mother the exact same id.

Comment: @Pointy: GIGO. the weirdest part is that her name's DARIETTA instead of EVE...

Comment: Wow, these are all helpful. Thanks for the pointy'ers. :) Out of curiosity, is there a good way to do a "recursion validation" check without just stacking a bunch of ifs, or? Either way - since @dandavis provided the magic code, do you mind making that an official answer so I can give you the award?

Comment: ideally, when working with recursion, you don't have self-referencing input. if you do, then yes, you'll need to filter it somehow, depending on need and situation. since the solution hinges on bad data, i don't feel an answer would be very helpful to anyone else, but i'm glad to help.

Comment: Actually, there's enough manually created databases out there that seeing references for how to CATCH bad data input is really helpful. I won't force you but I think any problem that has an answer is ultimately helpful in the grand scope.

Answer (score 0):

try this non-recursive version:

```
var stack = []
var visited = {}
var ids = []
function getLineage(id) {
    stack.push(id)
    traverse()
    create_result(id)
}
function traverse() {
    while(stack.length > 0) {
        var id = stack.pop()
        var data = horses[i]
        if(data) {
            visited[id] = data
            ids.push[id]
            stack.push(data.father)
            stack.push(data.mother)
        }
    }
}
function create_result(id) {
    for(var i=ids.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        var x = visited[ids[i]]
        var y = {name:x.name,father:visited[x.father],mother:visited[x.mother]}
        visited[ids[i]] = y
    }
    return visited[id]
};
```

Comment: you can hold current branch in another stack variable and check for loops